# Create a copy/test Nation Builder site?

Tags: testing, copy, workflow

New to nation builder and looking to edit a live nation builder site.  I'd like to make a copy / sandbox of the site I could use for testing.

Any insight on how to copy a nationbuilder site or testing/dev workflow for nationbuilder would be useful.

I am aware of: http://nationbuilder.com/theme_sync and the ability to download a theme, but still looking for a way to copy content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone an individual site and share it with yourself and others. This should help - http://nationbuilder.com/site_sharing